# How can I make Bot Framework Prompt Choices only accept exact matches?

Tags: botframework

In the Bot Framework (NodeJS api), how can I force my prompt choices to only match with user input that matches exactly, rather than doing partial or fuzzy matching? Should I create a custom prompt for something so basic?

I'm using this code:

```
var choices_films = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('films.json', 'utf8'));
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Say one film", choices_films, { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button, minScore: 1.0 });
```

And films.json contains this:

```
[
    {
        "value": "House of Cards",
        "synonyms": ["house of cards", "house cards", "cards"]
},
{
        "value": "House of Kings",
        "synonyms": ["house kings", "house of kings", "kings"]
}, 
{
        "value": "Matrix Revolutions",
        "synonyms": ["matrix", "revolutions"]
}]
```

If I say "house", then "House of Cards" is selected, because it appears first, and the bot framework is ignoring my "minScore: 1.0". Any idea would be welcome, because at the moment I have to do a custom choice or use middleware to capture it and fix it...

Comment: Can you further explain your question?  Code examples would help too

Comment: Language? C# or Node?

Comment: Hi Daniel -- I think this is a good and answerable question, and I edited it to clean up the wording a bit. That said, as @EzequielJadib mentioned, if you're able to clarify whether you're using the C# or Node.js SDK when asking questions about the Bot Framework, it's easier for people to provide answers for your specific scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the C# version of the SDK, then there's a [PromptDialog.Choice signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptdialog.choice?view=botbuilder-3.11.0) which includes [a parameter called `minScore`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L619), described as follows:

> (Optional) minimum score from 0.0 - 1.0 needed for a recognized choice to be considered a match. The default value is "0.4".

If minScore is set to a value less than 1, then fuzzy matching will be used, but if you set the value to 1, then only an exact match will be accepted.

The method signature is as follows:

```
public static void Choice<T>(IDialogContext context, ResumeAfter<T> resume, IPromptOptions<T> promptOptions, bool recognizeChoices = true, bool recognizeNumbers = true, bool recognizeOrdinals = true, double minScore = 0.4)
```

If you're using the Node.js version of the SDK, it looks like there's an [equivalent `minScore` parameter](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptchoicefeatures.html#minscore) in the IPromptChoiceFeatures interface ([link to source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/9881866ce083442c7f1ca5555f22b85bbe5f52c2/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts#L61)), which is [passed to the PromptChoice constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/9881866ce083442c7f1ca5555f22b85bbe5f52c2/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts#L76), so you should be able to set the threshold similarly there as well - but beyond that I can't speak to the specific syntax as I haven't worked with the Node.js SDK personally.

Comment: Thanks @SamHanley for the tip, I am using NodeJS, but I tried use minScore 1.0, and it is still doing partial matching. Its the code that I am using:  `builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Choose one option", choices_list, { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button, minScore: 1.0 });`

Comment: Can you create a simple example which reproduces the issue? As I said, I've admittedly only used the C# version, rather than Node, but without any clearer info about your use case, all I can say is that this is the code that should work.

Comment: I think that the problem happens when you use multiple words like synonyms in different options, and you have repeated words. For example: "house of kings" and "house of cards".

Comment: Again - unless you edit your question to include an actual, concrete code sample/scenario which reproduces  the issue, all I can do is tell you that what you're reporting should not happen if you use this code. This is the correct answer to your question at the level of specificity you asked - if you want to get a more specific answer, then you need better details about your *specific* issue.

Comment: Done! Tell me if you need any other info

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to reproduce the problem myself later on and see if I can provide any more advice.